# How to run pt-kill on CentOS Server

Tags: centos, mysql, percona

So, I have downloaded pt-kill file with:

```
wget percona.com/get/pt-kill
```

Now, I tried running it, but everything is not working? How do you run this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chmod u+x pt-kill
./pt-kill
```

Of course, you need Perl and likely a number of perl modules installed. Perl will tell you what is missing, but it appears they also included the most important modules into the file.

Comment: @JennyD Ups :-)

Comment: can I install all perl dependecies at once or I need to go one by one?

Comment: If you now them all, you can install all at once. If you don't, Perl will stop at the first failed module and name it, so you have to install turn by turn.

Comment: ok, I figured out --user and --pasword flags, but command is taking too long to print out stuck proccesses, is there a limit flag?

Comment: This is my problem (at least I think it's cuz of this) https://imgur.com/a/vFtJJsa

Comment: After I do mysql restart, they just pop up again after some time... This is website in production, so I can't like delete entire sql and reinstall it or something :(